# Bluetooth speaker inconsistent sound

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I use ubuntu 18.04. I have recently started using a bluetooth speaker with my computer instead of the cord. What I have noticed is that the sound is inconsistent. It plays with silent patches here and there after a few seconds. The speaker works flawlessly with my phone.

Answer (score 0):

fixed. I just installed PulseAudio volume control and it fixed it.